# Having trouble with mathematical proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, quantifiers

As the title implies, I'm totally lost with proofs.  I'm currently writing the section that is called the "Scratch Work" section, where we have to write a sequence of steps, outlining our logic, before we write our actual proof.  So I'm middle of working on this and it is confusing the heck out of me.  This is what I have, but I am not confident in any of the steps at all.

Original question:

Let A, B and C be sets such that A and B \ C are disjoint. 
Prove that A ∩ B ⊆ C.

```
Givens:                                       Goals:
1) Sets A and B\C are disjoint                A ∩ B ⊆ C

Let x be arbitrary

2) ∀x[(x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∉ (B\C))]                 ∀x(x ∈ A ∩ B → x ∈ C)

Universal Instantiation             

3) x ∈ A ∧ x ∉ B\C                           x ∈ A ∩ B → x ∈ C

Applying deduction method   

4) x ∈ A ∩ B(new premise after deduction)    x ∈ C

5) x ∈ A ∧ x ∈ B    (set intersection def, 4)

6) x ∈ A            (sim, 3)

7) x ∉ B\C          (sim, 3)

8) x ∈ B            (sim, 5)
```

I have no idea if the switching from the first given and goal to the second given and goal is correct (switching to quantifier statements) and I dont know how to get to the goal.  Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT - Solution proposal:

Scratch Work:

```
Givens:                                     Goals:
1) Sets A and B\C are disjoint              A ∩ B ⊆ C
   A ∩ (B\C) = ∅

Let x be arbitrary

2) ∀x(x ∉ A ∩ (B\C))                        ∀x(x ∈ A ∩ B → x ∈ C)

Universal Instantiation             

3) x ∉ A ∩ (B\C)                            x ∈ A ∩ B → x ∈ C

Applying deduction method   

4) x ∈ A ∩ B    (new premise after deduction)   x ∈ C

5) x ∉ A ∧ (B\C)        (set intersection def, 3)

6) x ∉ (B\C)            (sim, 5)

7) x ∈ A ∧ B            (set intersection def, 4)

8) x ∈ B                (sim, 7)

9) x ∈ C                (definition of set difference, 6 and 8)
```

Comment: To me doing like that is more confusing than anything, use more words

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot to say that this is the "Scratch work" portion of the proof, not the english paragraph version.  We are instructed to do "scratch work" in sequence like this, prior to writing the proof itself, to get our logic straightened out before we write.

Comment: If you ask me that is just a bad habit, if it works for you shoot for it, for me it is a catastrophy, but onto business, what is it you exactly have trouble with?

Comment: Its not that I want to do it this way, its the way we are forced to do it in my class.  I'm just having an issue proving my new goal of x belongs to c.

Comment: For what it's worth I think the way you wrote is very presentable and intelligible.  Your starting hypothesis was badly translated, $A$ and $B\setminus C$ being disjoint means that $A\cap (B\setminus C)=\varnothing$. What you should be doing is using this hypothesis to prove that $\forall x(x\in A\cap B\to x\in C)$.

Comment: @GitGud, I honestly questioned whether I translated that statement correctly, and now that makes perfect sense.  The set is empty if they are disjoint.

Comment: Should this be tagged as homework-and-exercises, which I presume it is?

Comment: @QuantumFool , sorry, it should.  I'll be honest and admit I don't know all of the etiquette of this forum, and I didn't mean to not explain that it was homework.  All of my previous questions state whether a question was homework related or not.  I didn't know there was a tag for it ether.

Comment: Quick question @GitGud, is the disjoint portion of this question also equal to this? ¬∃x(x∈A∩B ∧ x∈C)

Comment: @joe_04_04 Nope, it should be one of the following $$\begin{align}&\neg \exists x(x\in A\land x\in B\setminus C),\\
&\neg \exists x(x\in A\land x\in B\land \underbrace{\neg x\in  C}_{\small\text{notice the}\\\small\text{difference?}}),\\
&\forall x((x\in A\land x\in B\setminus C)\to x\in \varnothing),\end{align}$$ etc. I don't know what would be the most "direct" formalization of the statement in your class. Perhaps there's some info regarding this on your notes.

Comment: Oh boy, this is what I actually used for my homework, ¬∃x(x∈A∧x∈B∖C), which I switched to ∀x(x ∉ A ∩ (B\C)) with quantifier negation, but for some reason wrote it down wrong on the comment above when recalling it from memory.  Thank you, this cleared it all up.  I approached it a bit differently than the user below suggested, as I used deduction to add a new given of x ∈ A ∩ B and a new goal of x ∈ C.  I was able to get all the givens down to x  ∈ B and x ∉ to B \ C, Therefore, x  ∈ C, due to the set difference definition.

Comment: @joe_04_04 Sounds good. I suggested you add your final work to this post as an answer if you think it's correct. It will be a way to confirm your work.

Comment: I added it in, but I'm not 100 percent confident that its error proof.  This is just the scratch work, but the scratch work should prove that x ∈ C, which should prove that the intersection of A and B is a subset of C.

Comment: @joe_04_04 I read it. It looks good. I say "looks" because I don't know what rules you have available and how they work so I'm just assuming certain things from the way the rules are written.

Comment: Yep, this is just the scratch work, so it's not super clean, but I'll try to write the formal proof much neater.  Thank you very much @GitGud, your help has been really generous.  Thank you.

Comment: @joe_04_04 No worries. Good work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in A\cap B$, then we have $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. As we have $A$ and $B-C$ are disjoint it implies that $A\cap(B-C)=\emptyset$. That means as $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$ that $x$ must be in $C$ as $B-C=\{x:x\in B, x\notin C\}$ to as otherwise it cannot be equal to the empty set. Ergo $A\cap B\subseteq C$.